# Google drive API - get user who has created permission (shared a file)

Tags: php, google-api, google-drive-api

I have PHP app using google/apiclient lib and I want to retrieve the user who created permission on file or folder.

I there any way or API I can get the information on who has created the Permission?

This is Permission object I have:

```
0 => Google_Service_Drive_Permission^ {#166
  #collection_key: "teamDrivePermissionDetails"
  +allowFileDiscovery: null
  +deleted: false
  +displayName: "My Drives"
  +domain: null
  +emailAddress: "shared@mydomain.com"
  +expirationTime: null
  +id: "42334331410813143544"
  +kind: "drive#permission"
  #permissionDetailsType: "Google_Service_Drive_PermissionPermissionDetails"
  #permissionDetailsDataType: "array"
  +photoLink: "https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/a-/Abrbrb7k54odEg7qpULhrrzPcNImd7EBgBLgUOPeK=s64"
  +role: "organizer"
  #teamDrivePermissionDetailsType: "Google_Service_Drive_PermissionTeamDrivePermissionDetails"
  #teamDrivePermissionDetailsDataType: "array"
  +type: "user"
  +view: null
  #internal_gapi_mappings: []
  #modelData: []
  #processed: []
  +"teamDrivePermissionDetails": array:1 [
    0 => Google_Service_Drive_PermissionTeamDrivePermissionDetails^ {#62
      +inherited: false
      +inheritedFrom: null
      +role: "organizer"
      +teamDrivePermissionType: "member"
      #internal_gapi_mappings: []
      #modelData: []
      #processed: []
    }
  ]
  +"permissionDetails": array:1 [
    0 => Google_Service_Drive_PermissionPermissionDetails^ {#1151
      +inherited: false
      +inheritedFrom: null
      +permissionType: "member"
      +role: "organizer"
      #internal_gapi_mappings: []
      #modelData: []
      #processed: []
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

#### Sadly there is no way of retrieving information about the user who created the permission using Drive API.

If you check the `Permissions` resource [here](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/permissions) you can notice that there is no field which refers to the user who created the permission.

*If you are an admin* however, you might want to check the Reports API documentation [here](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/reports/v1/appendix/activity/drive) as it provides some insight on how to retrieve certain activity events, including the ones related to the [change of permissions](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/reports/v1/appendix/activity/drive#change_user_access).

If you would like to have a field similar to this present in the Drive API, I encourage you to file a feature request on Google's Issue Tracker [here](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=191650&template=824106) and provide all the necessary details.

#### Reference

- [Drive API v3 Permissions Resource](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/permissions);
- [Reports API Drive Audit Activity Events](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/reports/v1/appendix/activity/drive).

Comment: Thank you @ale13. The activity API is what I was looking for... There is always "personName" and it is key I can compare with a list of known users. It is sufficient for my case.

$activity->getActors()[0]->getUser()->getKnownUser()->getPersonName();